# GTk+3 version not the lastest stable version

Tags: raspbian, apt

I'm in trouble with gtk version i think. When i run `pkg-config --modversion gtk+-3.0` in my Raspberry Pi that is running Raspbian OS, i get 3.14.5 version.

If i try to update with `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade`, i have the same version.

How i can update to gtk+-3.20 version that is the latest stable version?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many hours trying resolve the problem, i change the path of `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to `/usr/local/lib` and resolve the problem. This selects the last gtk+ version installed.

You can run `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD-LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/lib`

Answer (score 0):

To do that you'll need to download the latest Gtk source code and have it compiled on the PI. Note that to build Gtk you'll have dependencies which need to be updated also. The latest stable release is Gtk+ 3.22 and you can check the repository on [Github](https://github.com/GNOME/gtk). The official repository should be on git.gnome.org which is down atm.

Comment: Thanks i'm making this.. but i have problems with the older versions i think.. How can i remove older versions?

Comment: Now, when i try to compile my program after i installed gtk+3.22 i get this error `undefined reference to 'pango_fc_font_map_config_changed'`

Comment: As I said, Gtk+ has dependencies, pango, cairo are immediate ones but there are more. You shouldn't remove the actual Gtk version or your PI will, probably,  stop working. Gtk is a framework, GLib, DBus etc are also required. It's a huge task just on the framework itself. I would suggest you to keep both versions running. 3.14.5 used on the PI and the new one for your developing/testing purposes.